# How to get hourly currency rates in forex-python?

Tags: python, forex

I try to get exchange rates and use forex_python. According to offical documentation I enter date and time. But when I change hour it still returns the same rate. I mean for example rate for 09:00 or 14:00 is the same? How can I change it to get hourly historical currencies? or should I use another API?
thank you in advance.

```
import datetime
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
date_obj=datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 18, 9, 0, 0)
c.convert('USD', 'TRY', 1, date_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go look at the source.  It only uses the date part, not the time.  It only stores one price per day.